# Statement enabling in Yugabyte YSQL

Tags: database, bigdata, yugabytedb

I want to see all the YSQL statements that are being executed. Something like log_statement=all in postgres. How do I enable statement logging in Yugabyte YSQL?

Answer (score 3):

If you're running a local cluster, `cd` into your data directory and find the file `postgresql.conf` in `node-1/disk-1/pg_data`. You can change the value of the log_statement parameter here (and uncomment it). The valid values for this field are `none`,`ddl`,`mod` and `all` (like in Postgres). This will modify logging for the node-1. 
You can similarly change the logging behavior for the other nodes. 
For the changes to take effect, restart the cluster using `./bin/yb-ctl restart`. 
By default, the logs are in `postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log` located in `node-1/disk-1/yb-data/tserver/logs` (for node-1). You can change the log_filename inside `postgresql.conf` as well.

If you're running a distributed cluster, locate the pg_data directory on your node, edit the `postgresql.conf` file as above and then restart the cluster.

 
Hope this helps!